# Multinomial test from finitely many possible multinomial distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multinomial-distribution

my area of focus is within pure math, but I've found myself in a situation where I need to run some sort of statistical test, and I am hoping someone can point me towards the correct test or framework. Apologies in advance if my language is incorrect or imprecise, and please correct me if any of my assumptions are wrong! My situation is as follows:

I have am running independent trials where each trial gives me one of 25 different (categorical) results. After $n$ trials, my result is essentially a length 25 vector where each component is $n_i$ and $\sum n_i = n$ , where $n_i$ is the number of times the trial reported "bin" $i$.

I know that the data I am sampling actually comes from one of 350 possible multinomial distributions, each of which to me is the following data: $p_i$ for $i = 1, \cdots, k$ where $\sum p_i = 1$.

My understanding is that for any one of these 350 possible distributions, I could run a chi-squared goodness of fit test which would give me a p-value for rejecting the null hypothesis that my data actually comes from that distribution. However, **my question is:** is there a test that can answer some version of "with the knowledge that my data *must* come from one of these finitely many (350) multinomial distributions, which one does it best fit and ideally is there a number (p-value?) that measures my confidence in this answer? Again, the stats element of this is fairly new to me so please let me know if I need to rephrase this.

Complicating the issue is that I need to code this into the math programming language I use (MAGMA), so I am looking for an explanation of the theory here in a way that I can build the test myself, rather than just a link to something from R or something like that.

Does anyone have a reference (textbook, paper, etc.) that explains the sort of test I am describing?

Comment: There are many such tests, which fall into broad categories; probability tests and tests like AIC. Moreover, there is software that automatically lists results of multiple tests of multiple attempted models. And so, there are a plethora of answers to your question, no single one of which would be entirely satisfactory.

Comment: Hi Carl, thanks for your comment. What sort of software would this be? Maybe I can give you a little more specificity on the kind of test I need, which I have not been able to find on my own. Rather than multiple hypothesis testing where the tests are assumed to be independent, mine are very *not* independent: I have 350 possible distributions, and I know that ONE and only one of them is correct. What sort of framework would help me here? My "models" are very simple, as they are all multinomial distributions.

Comment: Mathematica language has, for example, [FindDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html). If you look through that exhaustively, you will see lots of test types and alternatives.

Comment: [Equivalence tests for multinomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#Equivalence_tests_for_multinomial_distributions) may be of some interest for you.